# Who coined the term "the Lululemon Belt"?

Tags: united-states, terminology, republican-party, demographics

An [article at Politico by Jonathan Martin](https://www.politico.com/news/magazine/2023/10/18/gop-party-house-speaker-00122371) refers to constituency or faction (apparently) made up of white female moderate suburban Republicans in "the Lululemon belt — from Buckhead to Bala Cynwyd."

Lululemon is a leading seller of high end yoga apparel. Bala Cynwyd is a southern suburb of Philadelphia. Buckhead is in northern suburban Atlanta.

The larger context of the quote in which this appears is as follows:

> Much like McCarthy, the once-promising Trump alternative, Florida Gov.
> Ron DeSantis, sought to blur the lines between the pre- and post-Trump
> party. DeSantis was, he said all but explicitly, the way out of the
> party having to decide.
>
> He could deliver all the Magalicious pugnacity and enough of the
> populism to Trump’s legions. But the 40-something father of three
> young children would do it in a package that wouldn’t send the voters
> of **the Lululemon belt — from Buckhead to Bala Cynwyd** — back to Joe
> Biden’s column.

Is this demographic-geographic descriptor and turn of phrase original to Martin in this article, or is this term one that was already in use? If so, when and where?

Are there other terms that are commonly used that identify the same demographic within the Republican Party in the United States?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. In my opinion this term is clearly Martin's, but what sort of evidence are you expecting beyond the lack of older, relevant results from a web search?

Comment: It related terminology related to the description of a political group (cf. the Bible Belt). I'm interested in finding potential sourcing because doing so would tap into a vein of interesting discussion of political identity and the factions that make up the political coalitions of the major U.S. political parties.

Comment: *refers to constituency or faction (apparently) made up of white female moderate suburban Republicans* Where does that writer say that "Lululemon belt" refers to "white female moderate suburban Republicans"?

Comment: Journalists/writers are constantly coining new phrases, hoping their new phrase catches on and they become that much more famous. (Most of the time they fail.)

Comment: @user103496 It is a reasonable inference from the term in context. It is talking about a Republican faction or demographic. It could potentially swing to Biden so it is presumably moderate. The end points are predominantly white conservative upper middle class suburbs. Lululemon is associated with a pretty distinct group of customers (overwhelmingly female, generally not rural and not wanting to return to the 1950s). Presumably it would run through suburban areas in DE, VA, NC, SC, and GA.

Comment: You should not state then that the article "refers" to such, but that you have made an inference that may or may not be correct.

Comment: @user103496 Hence the qualifier "apparently".

Comment: @ohwileke I you want to "tap into a vein of interesting discussion of political identity" then elaborate a question about that. The trivial etymology question is not so interesting and has already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan Martin.

> Is this demographic-geographic descriptor and turn of phrase original to Martin in this article

Yes.

> is this term one that was already in use?

[No.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Lululemon+belt%22+republicans)

Comment: And on what basis do you reach this conclusion?

Comment: @ohwilleke: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Lululemon+belt%22+republicans "About 19 results" which include this post and the cited article. All other results are irrelevant. (I had also never heard of this phrase "Lululemon belt" in connection to Republicans.)

Comment: You might be right, but one of the joys of Politics.SE is that its brain trust can figure out things that a simple Google search does not.